# Why I use responsive for different resolution at "class" but it does not active?

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I wrote a very simple html file and here is my html file (with helped from stackoverflow friends, it worked very well, as designed)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.course-item {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 260px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.row.no-gutters {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid wide container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
      <div class="course-item">
        <h1>course 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
      <div class="course-item">
        <h1>course 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
      <div class="course-item">
        <h1>course 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
      <div class="course-item">
        <h1>course 4</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my grid.css file, sorry I must upload file because it is too long to copy paste to stackover flow
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ayr9645d0wn5giv/grid.css/file

My problem is, I wrote in my css file and designed for pc, tablet, phone as l, m, c as you can see  in the grid.css file I wrote c-0 to c-12, m-1 to m-12, l-1 to l-12.

But, when I shrink the screen, it does not appear as design. For example, I wrote `<div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">` means at mobile, it must display two columns, but here it display

[image: picture when I use m-6 but it not display two columns]

And, when I shrink more, it does not appear two columns, it still appear one column as you can see in this picture

[image: picture when I use c-6, it must display 2 columns but it display 1 column]

Could you please help me for this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please extract just enough CSS to show us the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to include your ***grid.css*** file as a link in the `<head></head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/grid.css">
```

I see two columns in this snippet if I fully paste it in the CSS area:

```css
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid.wide {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

.row.no-gutters {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.col {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

.row.no-gutters .col {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.c-0 {
    display: none;
}

.c-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
    max-width: 8.33333%;
}

.c-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
}

.c-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}

.c-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}

.c-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
    max-width: 41.66667%;
}

.c-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.c-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
    max-width: 58.33333%;
}

.c-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
}

.c-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
}

.c-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
    max-width: 83.33333%;
}

.c-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
    max-width: 91.66667%;
}

.c-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.c-o-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333%;
}

.c-o-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66667%;
}

.c-o-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.c-o-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333%;
}

.c-o-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66667%;
}

.c-o-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.c-o-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333%;
}

.c-o-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66667%;
}

.c-o-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.c-o-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333%;
}

.c-o-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66667%;
}


/* >= Tablet */

@media (min-width: 740px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: -8px;
        margin-right: -8px;
    }
    .col {
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
    }
    .m-0 {
        display: none;
    }
    .m-1,
    .m-2,
    .m-3,
    .m-4,
    .m-5,
    .m-6,
    .m-7,
    .m-8,
    .m-9,
    .m-10,
    .m-11,
    .m-12 {
        display: block;
    }
    .m-1 {
        flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
        max-width: 8.33333%;
    }
    .m-2 {
        flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
        max-width: 16.66667%;
    }
    .m-3 {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
    .m-4 {
        flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
        max-width: 33.33333%;
    }
    .m-5 {
        flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
        max-width: 41.66667%;
    }
    .m-6 {
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    .m-7 {
        flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
        max-width: 58.33333%;
    }
    .m-8 {
        flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
        max-width: 66.66667%;
    }
    .m-9 {
        flex: 0 0 75%;
        max-width: 75%;
    }
    .m-10 {
        flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
        max-width: 83.33333%;
    }
    .m-11 {
        flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
        max-width: 91.66667%;
    }
    .m-12 {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .m-o-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333%;
    }
    .m-o-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66667%;
    }
    .m-o-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .m-o-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333%;
    }
    .m-o-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66667%;
    }
    .m-o-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    .m-o-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333%;
    }
    .m-o-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66667%;
    }
    .m-o-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }
    .m-o-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333%;
    }
    .m-o-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66667%;
    }
}


/* PC medium resolution > */

@media (min-width: 1113px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: -12px;
        margin-right: -12px;
    }
    .row.sm-gutter {
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .col {
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }
    .row.sm-gutter .col {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .l-0 {
        display: none;
    }
    .l-1,
    .l-2,
    .l-2-4,
    .l-3,
    .l-4,
    .l-5,
    .l-6,
    .l-7,
    .l-8,
    .l-9,
    .l-10,
    .l-11,
    .l-12 {
        display: block;
    }
    .l-1 {
        flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
        max-width: 8.33333%;
    }
    .l-2 {
        flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
        max-width: 16.66667%;
    }
    .l-2-4 {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
    .l-3 {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
    .l-4 {
        flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
        max-width: 33.33333%;
    }
    .l-5 {
        flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
        max-width: 41.66667%;
    }
    .l-6 {
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    .l-7 {
        flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
        max-width: 58.33333%;
    }
    .l-8 {
        flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
        max-width: 66.66667%;
    }
    .l-9 {
        flex: 0 0 75%;
        max-width: 75%;
    }
    .l-10 {
        flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
        max-width: 83.33333%;
    }
    .l-11 {
        flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
        max-width: 91.66667%;
    }
    .l-12 {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .l-o-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333%;
    }
    .l-o-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66667%;
    }
    .l-o-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .l-o-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333%;
    }
    .l-o-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66667%;
    }
    .l-o-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    .l-o-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333%;
    }
    .l-o-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66667%;
    }
    .l-o-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }
    .l-o-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333%;
    }
    .l-o-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66667%;
    }
}


/* Tablet - PC low resolution */

@media (min-width: 740px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .wide {
        width: 644px;
    }
}


/* > PC low resolution */

@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1239px) {
    .wide {
        width: 984px;
    }
    .wide .row {
        margin-left: -12px;
        margin-right: -12px;
    }
    .wide .row.sm-gutter {
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .wide .col {
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }
    .wide .row.sm-gutter .col {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .wide .l-0 {
        display: none;
    }
    .wide .l-1,
    .wide .l-2,
    .wide .l-2-4,
    .wide .l-3,
    .wide .l-4,
    .wide .l-5,
    .wide .l-6,
    .wide .l-7,
    .wide .l-8,
    .wide .l-9,
    .wide .l-10,
    .wide .l-11,
    .wide .l-12 {
        display: block;
    }
    .wide .l-1 {
        flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
        max-width: 8.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-2 {
        flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
        max-width: 16.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-2-4 {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
    .wide .l-3 {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
    .wide .l-4 {
        flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
        max-width: 33.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-5 {
        flex: 0 0 41.66667%;
        max-width: 41.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-6 {
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    .wide .l-7 {
        flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
        max-width: 58.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-8 {
        flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
        max-width: 66.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-9 {
        flex: 0 0 75%;
        max-width: 75%;
    }
    .wide .l-10 {
        flex: 0 0 83.33333%;
        max-width: 83.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-11 {
        flex: 0 0 91.66667%;
        max-width: 91.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-12 {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66667%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333%;
    }
    .wide .l-o-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66667%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.course-item {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 260px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.row.no-gutters {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

</style>
  <body>
    <div class="grid wide container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
          <div class="course-item">
            <h1>course 1</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
          <div class="course-item">
            <h1>course 2</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
          <div class="course-item">
            <h1>course 3</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l-3 m-6 c-6">
          <div class="course-item">
            <h1>course 4</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Also here: https://jsfiddle.net/gw6at58x/